# Orientation of a Vector Space and the Homology of a pair

Tags: homology-cohomology, characteristic-classes, orientation

I am stuck at the following argument in the book Charcteristic Classes by Milnor & Stasheff page 96:

> A choice of orientation for V corresponds to a choice of
> one of the two possible generators for the singular homology group
> $H_n(V, V_0; Z)$.

I was able to proof that homology group above mentioned is actually isomorphic to Integers. This is what they have explained in the next few lines.

> Choose some orientation preserving linear embedding
> $$\sigma : \Delta^n\to V $$
> which maps the barycenter of $ \Delta^n$ to the zero vector,hence maps the
> boundary of $ \Delta^n$ into $V_0$.Then $ \Delta^n$ is a singular n-simplex representing
> an element in the group of relative n-cycles $Z_n(V, V_0; Z)$.

Here are my problems:

1. What about the existence of such a map.
2. If the barycentre is being mapped to zero then why it implies the boundary has to be non-zero?
3. Why does all this implies that it has to be a relative n-cycle.

Kindly help!!
Any suggestions are valuable.
Regards